# Can Azure DevOps pipelines be run in a specific order?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-pipelines

Our repository contains a couple of CI pipelines for some services as a mono-repo. These pipelines deploy images to a docker image registry.

I want to run a separate pipeline to do the CD part, which pulls in the images from the registry and deploys them in a cluster. Is this dependency amongst different yaml pipelines possible in Azure DevOps?

In essense:

Let's assume we have Pipelines S1, S2, S3 for services.
I want to run Pipeline 'Deploy' after all three pipelines have finished.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, yes you can. But I don't think it's possible to trigger 1 pipeline when 3 others are completed.

You can trigger them 1 after another though, see the Microsoft Docs for reference: [Trigger one pipeline after another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: yes, this is the doc I was referring to as well. Couldn't find much there.